# missing required option :name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am trying to set up AWS, and carrierwave to upload pictures from my website. I keep getting the error 'missing required option :name' when I try to upload/update the posts though. I have followed tutorials to set up my S3 account and to get carrierwave.rb set up. Please let me know if you have any ideas!

carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 config.storage    = :aws
 config.aws_bucket = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
 config.aws_acl    = 'public-read'
 config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
 config.aws_attributes = {
   expires: 1.week.from_now.httpdate,
   cache_control: 'max-age=604800'
 }

 config.aws_credentials = {
   access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
   secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
   region:            ENV['AWS_REGION']
 }
end
```

.env example

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME=*****
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*****
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*****
AWS_REGION=*****
```

portfolio_uploader.rb

```
class PortfolioUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :aws

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the *exact* error? When/where do you see this error?

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 102ms (ActiveRecord: 23.0ms)


  
ArgumentError (missing required option :name)

Is the error. It happens when i try to update or create a portfolio item with an image.

Comment: Try to use `ENV.fetch` instead of `ENV[]`

Comment: Just tried .fetch and still get the same error

Comment: can u post error log also ?

Comment: There isn't much more than that in the logs:  ↳ app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:43
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m
  ↳ app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:43
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 75ms (ActiveRecord: 19.2ms)


  
ArgumentError (missing required option :name):
  
app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:43:in `block in update'
app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:42:in `update'

Comment: Seeing the same error since switching from `fog` to `carrierwave-aws`. :name does not seem to be related to the actual activerecord model validation.

Comment: @StephSimpson - I'm going through the same issue.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this issue too. The error message is deceptive. I found that it is actually the `config.aws_bucket = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']` line that was causing the issue. If `config.aws_bucket` is `nil` (such as when the `ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']` is unset, you will get the deceptive `missing required option :name` in the console.

Comment: How did you fixed it?

Comment: you set S3_BUCKET_NAME environment variable to the proper bucket name.

Comment: This was the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had an identical issue, try to restart the rails server, when you are making any changes to your config folder you have to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I saw Carrierwave.rb file was deleted from my App's config >> Initializers folder. recreating the same fixed the issue. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you've got your bucket name / keys in an encrypted credentials file but don't have your `.key` file(s) setup correctly / Rails can't read the credentials file, FYI!